# Can max-stale be set in the response header?

Tags: http, http-headers, browser-cache, cache-control

Can max-stale be set in the response header for it to be used by the request on the client side? The documentation here - [Cache-Control: Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control#Syntax), specifically the "Cache response directives" section makes it appear as if max-stale is not part of the response header. Is this only used by client to make decision how much longer it will use the stale resource and server/application has no say in it? If so, what can be set on the response to simulate the functionality of max-stale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No max-stale cannot be used in the response. It’s meant to be used by the client to override the cache defaults. “Gimme this resource even if it’s technically a bit past it’s expiry date”. It would be used if there is a caching server between the client and the origin server.

To be honest, in my experience, request cache-control headers are rarely used, except to force refresh all the way back to origin server (`max-age=0`) for example when doing a “hard reload” with dev tools open. I’ve never seen a real world instance of `max-stale` as far as I can recall.

There is not equivalent on a response header. If a server is happy for a resource to be used for longer then it should just increase the `max-age` amount.

There is the `stale-while-revalidate` response option which allows a stale resource to be used for a limited period, to allow a quick reload of the page, while the browser checks and downloads a new version in the background for the next time. However support of it is limited at this time as shown at the bottom of that page you linked.

Comment: Thanks for the response. That was what I've gathered from my research, but I was also getting conflicting response internally, so I just wanted to make sure.

Comment: One more question. If max-stale happen to be placed in the response header, does the client simply ignore it?

Comment: max-stale is only defined as a request header. it would be ignored if put on a response

Comment: Yup. Same as if you put in other random HTTP header that was unrecognised. It's one of the nice features of HTTP that it's extendable this way as clients and servers just ignore headers they don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

Simulating the behaviour of `max-stale` on the response does not really make much sense. Server owns the resources and has an understanding of how those resources change over time. Server has to decide how critical a resource is and if it is ok for it be served stale. Also decide on some reasonable time limits for the resource to be re-validated such that the clients get fresh data most of the time. It is a balancing act on the server side. Too strict the setting, you are overloading your server with requests and client with network traffic. Too loose, your clients see an old representation.

A client can use `max-stale` to avoid any re-validation and get what is in the cache. you don't want to generate network requests unless it is really necessary. for example `must-revalidate` overrides `max-stale` so if the response has that header, even with `max-stale` you will hit the origin server no matter. Similarly with `no-cache` and `no-store`. So in that sense, server has a say in it. It can identify resources that CANNOT be used stale, even with `max-stale` and marks with the appropriate header.

Comment: Thank you for the additional clarification.